# How to update UI after a web service calling thread is finished

Tags: multithreading, blackberry

Questions about threads are in no shortage, I know, but I can't seem to find a "full" example of a thread doing http work and then coming back to update the UI.

I basically call a few web services upon app launch. I obviously don't want to freeze the UI so I would want to use a separate thread, right? I have found a bunch of examples online on how to get a new thread to perform some task. But I haven't yet found one that shows how to actually update the UI when the thread's task is done.

How do I know when the web service thread is done? Is there a callback method? Can I access the UI from this callback method if one exists.

Edit: (Here is some code)

```
//The activate method is called whenever my application gains focus.

public void activate(){

    DoSomething wsThread = new DoSomething();
    wsThread.start();
}

public void wsCallBack()
{
    myTabScreen.add(new ButtonField("Callback called"));
}

public class DoSomething extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            wsCallBack();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }           
    }
}
```

Very simple. But it never creates the button.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a "callback" system to notify the UI when the threads complete. Have a class that extends Thread and pass to it a reference of the class that should be called at the end. If you have a list of such classes that needs to be notified create a Vector on the Thread implementation to hold them. Override the run function and after doing everything you need to do simply call a method on the UI class (iterating through the vector if needed). So your classes may look like:

```
public class commThread extends Thread{

   MyUIClass callbackObj;

   public commThread(MyUIClass myUiClass){
      callbackObj = myUiClass;
   }

   public void run(){
      //do stuff
      callbackObj.callback();
   }

}
```

and your UI class:

```
public MyUIClass{

   public void callback(){
   //refresh the UI
   }
}
```

Of course if you have multiple threads running at the same time and calling the same UI object make sure to synchronize the callback method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. However I can't seem to start the new thread from my Main thread's activate() method, which is what I'm ultimately trying to do. Is this not allowed?

Comment: can you post some code and the error you get when you try to do this? What do you mean by your Main thread's activate method?

Comment: Have you tried writing to the standard output (using System.out.println) to see that the different functions get called? Try calling myTabScreen.invalidate() after adding the button to force a screen redraw.